# Table panel using MQL in Grafana doesn't have expected columns

Tags: google-cloud-platform, grafana

Let's say I have a custom metric 'runtime_in_seconds' in the GCP with three labels A, B, C.

I want to display this metric in a tabular form in Grafana. However, if I do either one of these two queries below, I only get two columns: One for the metric value and on for the combined 'group by' label values.

```
fetch gce_instance
| metric 'custom.googleapis.com/opencensus/runtime_in_seconds'
| group_by 10m,
    [value_runtime_in_seconds_mean: mean(value.runtime_in_seconds)]
| every 10m
| group_by
    [metric.A, metric.B, metric.C],
    [value_runtime_in_seconds_mean_sum:
       sum(runtime_in_seconds_mean)]

fetch gce_instance
| metric 'custom.googleapis.com/opencensus/runtime_in_seconds'
| group_by 10m,
    [value_runtime_in_seconds_mean: mean(value.runtime_in_seconds)]
| every 10m
```

Instead, I would like a table with the schema A | B | C | sum(runtime_in_seconds). If I display the queries as time series diagrams, I get the expected result. Hence, I don't think that the query should be the problem.

Comment: Hi `Thomas Wening` I think [label_replace](https://deploy.live/blog/today-i-learned-adding-labels-to-prometheus-queries/) function in prometheus might work in you case. Try using this and let us know if you are still facing some issues